# setActive() performance in IE9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9, kendo-grid

I'm working with the latest version of Telerik's Kendo Grid and they've added some code in a focusTable method that is calling setActive if the browser is msie. Selecting rows in the grid takes 1-2 seconds from click to highlight. Profiling the JS in IE9 reveals the setActive method as the single worst-performing JS method in the call stack. Unfortunately, because it is native JS, I can't see source to know what this method is actually doing.

Can anyone provide more insight on how setActive actually works and, more importantly, how can we adjust our code to make it more performant? I'm intentionally not posting code because there's quite a bit and I haven't yet pinpointed all the places that would be relevant to share.

Comment: If you have found an answer to this problem, please share over here...